# Using array_search to remove an element, a given amount of times

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to remove the element with the smallest value, for the given amount of times specified by `$inpSentences`.

```
$a = array(0 => 2, 1 => 1.5);
```

`$inpSentences` is 1

```
for($i = 0; $i != $inpSentences; i++){
  $min = min($a);
  $key1 = array_search($min, $a);
  unset($a[$key1]);
  echo($key1);
}

echo($a);
```

Hope someone's able to help - first time posting to StackOverflow. Also new to php.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain how your current code is not working the way you want it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest approach is probably to sort the array from lowest to highest and then slice off `$inpSentences` number of elements from the start.

Using `array_slice()`, you remove a specific number of elements from the beginning of the array. That means if you supply `$inpSentences` as the second argument (the array `$a` is the first argument), that's how many elements will get removed. To ensure that you always remove the lowest values, you `sort()` the array first.

```
$inpSentences = 3;                      // How many elements you want to remove
sort($a);                               // Sort the array
$new = array_slice($a, $inpSentences);  // Slice off $inpSentences elements from the start
print_r($new);                          // Prints the resulting array
```

For your example, where `$a = array(2, 1.5)`, it'd look like this

```
// Input-array
Array (
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 1.5
)
// Output array
Array (
    [0] => 2
)
```

- [Live demo](https://3v4l.org/LjiF2)
- [PHP.net on `array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)
- [PHP.net on `sort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a great way of tackling my problem.